# jQuery - dont send ajax query again after sending once

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am sending an ajax query to server for getting some HTML.

**I want to do this:**

- on first click send the query and append the `div` to `body` (My code works till here)
- if the button was clicked again then show the previously appended `div`.

Please note one thing that `action` for my ajax query is defined in the button in `data` attribute.

**Here is my jQuery code, it send ajax query on every click:**

```
jQuery('.open-box').click(function(){
    var action = jQuery(this).data('action');
    jQuery.ajax({
        type    : 'GET',
        url     : ajaxurl,
        data    : { action    : action},
        dataType: 'html',
        context: this,
        success: function (response) {
            jQuery(response).show().appendTo('body');
        },
    });
});
```

**Here is my button html**

```
<button class="open-box" data-action="test-html">Open box</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a jQuery expert but I think this solution is good:

now my code will check if `data-loaded` is true or false, if false then it will send ajax query, and change data-loaded to true.

```
jQuery('.open-box').click(function(){

    if (this.data('loaded')){
            jQuery(this).data('loaded', 'true');
        var action = jQuery(this).data('action');
        jQuery.ajax({
            type    : 'GET',
            url     : ajaxurl,
            data    : { action    : action},
            dataType: 'html',
            context: this,
            success: function (response) {
                jQuery(response).show().appendTo('body');

            },
        });
    }else{
        //show the appended div
    }
});
```

**My button HTML**

```
<button class="open-box" data-action="test-html" data-loaded="false">Open box</button>
```

Comment: If I click a 2nd time before the `ajax()` call returns it will trigger another request.

Comment: Moved `jQuery(this).data('loaded', 'true')` to top, hope it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/), which is an event handler that only runs once per element:

```
jQuery('.open-box').one('click', function(){
    var action = jQuery(this).data('action');
    jQuery.ajax({
        type    : 'GET',
        url     : ajaxurl,
        data    : { action    : action},
        dataType: 'html',
        context: this,
        success: function (response) {
            jQuery(response).show().appendTo('body');
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this that avoids polluting the parent scope with any lingering variables:

```
(function(){
    // This will be packaged into the handler as a closure
    var hasBeenClicked = false;

    jQuery('.open-box').click(function(){
        if(!hasBeenClicked) {
            var action = jQuery(this).data('action');
            jQuery.ajax({
                type    : 'GET',
                url     : ajaxurl,
                data    : { action    : action},
                dataType: 'html',
                context: this,
                success: function (response) {
                    jQuery(response).show().appendTo('body');
                },
            });
        }
        hasBeenClicked = true;
    });
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

You want one click to do the AJAX call, and after that all clicks to show the div.

```
// set one click to trigger ajax
jQuery('.open-box').one(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type    : 'GET',
        url     : ajaxurl,
        data    : { action    : action},
        dataType: 'html',
        context: this,
        success: function (response) {
            var createdDiv = jQuery(response);
            createdDiv.show().appendTo('body');
            // now hook up futher clicks to show the div
            jQuery('.open-box').click(function() {
                createdDiv.show();
            });
        },
    });
});
```

I am assuming you only have the one button (or whatever) with the class "open-box".

If you have multiple buttons with the class "open-box" then you can save the createdDiv in a data variable and retrieve the reference in the click handler.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach:

Put a div at the end of your body.

```
<body>
  ......
  <div id="append_container"></div>
</div>
```

Every time you click the button just update the content of the append_container. 
This way you don't have to worry to compare if the content is changed or not.

If you want to load the content only once, you can check if the container has any content or not. Then decide to make the ajax call.